# concatenating arrays stored in different dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have large number of dictionaries with about 20 keys in each but using two dictionaries with only 2 keys as example here:

```
dict1 = {'A':np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), 'B':np.array([[1,2],[4,5]])}
dict2 = {'A':np.array([[11,12,13],[14,15,16]]), 'B':np.array([[11,21],[41,51]])}
```

I am trying to obtain new dictionary with concatenated arrays such that:

```
combinedDict['A'] = 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16]])

combinedDict['B'] = 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 4,  5],
       [11, 21],
       [41, 51]])
```

How do I write a dictionary comprehension or other approach for the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
dictkeys = ('A', 'B')
dicts = dict1, dict2
{key: np.concatenate([d[key] for d in dicts]) for key in dictkeys}
```